# Modify a value in a Ruby hash only if present

Tags: ruby, hash, coding-style

I need to modify a hash value for a specific key but I do not want to add the key if it is not present, the long version would be:

```
if my_hash.has_key?( :key )
    my_hash[ :key ] = true if my_hash[ :key ] == 0
    my_hash[ :key ] = false if my_hash[ :key ] == 1
    # leave value alone if it is not 0 or 1
else
    # leave hash alone if key is not present
end
```

I wonder if there would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: You only need the second and third lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe with `case` statement

```
case my_hash[:key]                                                                                                                                                                   
when 0; my_hash[:key] = true                                                                                                                                                         
when 1; my_hash[:key] = false                                                                                                                                                        
end
```

Comment: This is a little bit different from the OP's code, it will set the value if the key is present but the value is nil.

Comment: @PatrickOscity don't understand you probably. just tested: if `my_hash = {key: nil}`, after this block it will be `nil` as before.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov sorry you're right in this case it doesn't matter. It matters when `nil` is a valid value that you may want to replace.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity :)

```
[0,1].include?(my_hash[:key]) && my_hash[:key] = my_hash[:key].zero?
```

Comment: This doesn't modify the hash, it just returns true or false. Right?

Comment: @mudosobwa You are right: I made an error while testing your suggestion.

Comment: @mudsosobwa It took me a while to understand your suggestion and I think it looks very Rubyish but I doubt very much if Kernighan and Ritchie would approve ;-)

Comment: Have you seen “Just out of curiosity” in front of it? I definitely upvoted the solution by @rustam-a-gasamov

Comment: You can shorten it by removing four spaces. Hey, wait a minute! This isn't [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: @CarySwoveland `h=my_hash&&` in front and `s/my_hash/h/g` in the rest eliminates another `3 * ('my_hash'.length - 1) - 'h=my_hash&&'.length = 7` symbols :-P

Answer (score 0):

One way may be to use a hash of "mapped" values, and then iterate over your normal hash and set values to it

```
value_map = { 0 => true, 1 => false }
my_hash.each { |k, v| my_hash[k] = value_map.include?(v) ? value_map[v] : v }
```

Comment: This works of you want to map a all key/value pairs - not a specific one (as in my case).

Comment: The body of the each will do that for a single value.

Comment: The point is that you can (and maybe even should) use a hash for mapping values, and not control flow statements.